# How to break the alignment of the date?

Tags: moderncv

I'm writing a cover letter for a presentation but the line with the following text:

**University of Baltimore, Department of mechatronics** is *broken* due to the presence of the line Date. As you can see, they lie on the same line:

[image]

That text *mechatronics* should be on the same line of *University of...* . I tried already some commands like: `\nolinebreak`, and the character `~` but it doesn't work.
Here is my minimal working example:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% "ModernCV" CV and Cover Letter
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.3 (29/10/16)
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.9cm} 

\nopagenumbers{}                                 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{John}  % Your first name
\familyname{Smith} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\address{xxxxx}{4444, Paris}
\mobile{+123456789}
\email{yyy@xxx.com}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\clearpage

\recipient{University of Baltimore, Department of mechatronics}{Prof. Micky Mouse \\Somewhere in the world\\98763 Baltimore} % Letter recipient
\date{Paris, \today} % Letter date
\opening{} % Opening greeting
\closing{Sincerely} % Closing phrase

\makelettertitle % Print letter title

\textbf{Letter of presentation}

Dear Prof....

\makeletterclosing % Print letter signature

\newpage

\end{document}
```

How can I change my code, so that the text and the date not on the same line lie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fool LaTeX with `\rlap`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, roman]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.9cm}

\nopagenumbers{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{John} % Your first name
\familyname{Smith} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\address{xxxxx}{4444, Paris}
\mobile{+123456789}
\email{yyy@xxx.com}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\clearpage

\recipient{University of Baltimore, Department of \rlap{mechatronics}}{Prof. Micky Mouse \\Somewhere in the world\\98763 Baltimore} % Letter recipient
\date{Paris, \today} % Letter date
\opening{} % Opening greeting
\closing{Sincerely} % Closing phrase

\makelettertitle % Print letter title

\textbf{Letter of presentation}

Dear Prof....

\makeletterclosing % Print letter signature

\newpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Well, I think the better solution would be to start the department line new on the left with

```
\recipient{University of Baltimore, \\Department of mechatronics}{Prof. Micky Mouse \\Somewhere in the world\\98763 Baltimore} % Letter recipient
%                                   ^^^^
```

If you do not want to do this you have to redefine command `\makeletterhead`. Inside it you find the code for the minipage placing the recipients address with

```
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth} 
    \raggedright%
    \addressfont%
    {\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}\\%
    \@recipientaddress%
  \end{minipage}
```

Change here the width of the minipage to your needs, for example to `.7\textwidth`:

```
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.7\textwidth} % <==================== .5\textwidth
    \raggedright%
    \addressfont%
    {\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}\\%
    \@recipientaddress%
  \end{minipage}
```

With the following code (please see that I used the current version 2.0.0 of class `moderncv`; it could be you are using an older version as indicated in this comment: `Version 1.3 (29/10/16)`):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% "ModernCV" CV and Cover Letter
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.3 (29/10/16)
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{classic} % head 1 body 1 foot 
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.9cm} 

\nopagenumbers{}                                 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makeletterhead}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputeletterlengths%
  % sender contact info
  \hfill%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}%
    % optional detailed information
    \if@details%
      \raggedleft%
      \addressfont\textcolor{color2}{%
        {\bfseries\upshape\@firstname~\@lastname}\@firstdetailselementfalse%
        % optional detailed information
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
        \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
          \makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}}\fi%
    \end{minipage}\\[1em]
  % recipient block
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.7\textwidth} % <==================== .5\textwidth
    \raggedright%
    \addressfont%
    {\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}\\%
    \@recipientaddress%
  \end{minipage}
  % date
  \hfill% US style
%  \\[1em]% UK style
  \@date\\[2em]% US informal style: "January 1, 1900"; UK formal style: "01/01/1900"
  % opening
  \raggedright%
  \@opening\\[1.5em]%
  % ensure no extra spacing after \makelettertitle due to a possible blank line
%  \ignorespacesafterend% not working
  \hspace{0pt}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}}
\makeatother

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{John}  % Your first name
\familyname{Smith} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\address{xxxxx}{4444, Paris}
\mobile{+123456789}
\email{yyy@xxx.com}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\clearpage

\recipient{University of Baltimore, Department of mechatronics}{Prof. Micky Mouse \\Somewhere in the world\\98763 Baltimore} % Letter recipient
\date{Paris, \today} % Letter date
\opening{} % Opening greeting
\closing{Sincerely} % Closing phrase

\makelettertitle % Print letter title

\textbf{Letter of presentation}

Dear Prof....

\makeletterclosing % Print letter signature

\newpage

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image]

As mentioned by @egreg you can use a shorter code by using package `etoolbox` which is already loaded by class `moderncv`. But please see that this  shorter code can only be used if you are using also version 2.0.0 of class `moderncv`. Please check your log file for the version number!

The shorter code

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% "ModernCV" CV and Cover Letter
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.3 (29/10/16)
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{classic} % head 1 body 1 foot 
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.9cm} 

\nopagenumbers{}

% to patch the code of moderncv, version 2.0.0
%\usepackage{etoolbox} % already loaded in moderncv <===================
\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}%
  {[t]{.5\textwidth}}% code to patch
  {[t]{0.7\textwidth}}% new code <======================================
  {}% success
  {}% failure


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{John}  % Your first name
\familyname{Smith} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\address{xxxxx}{4444, Paris}
\mobile{+123456789}
\email{yyy@xxx.com}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\clearpage

\recipient{University of Baltimore, Department of mechatronics}{Prof. Micky Mouse \\Somewhere in the world\\98763 Baltimore} % Letter recipient
\date{Paris, \today} % Letter date
\opening{} % Opening greeting
\closing{Sincerely} % Closing phrase

\makelettertitle % Print letter title

\textbf{Letter of presentation}

Dear Prof....

\makeletterclosing % Print letter signature

\newpage

\end{document}
```

results in the result shows above ...

Comment: More easily: at the end of the preamble add `\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}{[t]{.5\textwidth}}{[t]{0.7\textwidth}}{}{}`, after `\usepackage{etoolbox}`.